# Get X,Y,Z of a gripper

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

what is the simples approach to get the X,Y,Z coordinates in the base_link of a gripper or other joint?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41573/get-x,y,z-of-a-gripper./) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the simplest approach would be reading the TF transforms of the corresponding TF-frame (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf ).

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3